# Is it possible to load a different image based on a media query to improve load times?

Tags: css, performance, media-queries

For example, say I have a div and set the background image to 'X' that is displayed only for desktop sizes. When the query changes to mobile I would set the background image to 'Y'.

Would doing this make it so that on a mobile only 'Y' gets loaded and not 'X'? 'X' is a large image and 'Y' is small, I am trying to improve load times. Also if on a desktop would 'X' and 'Y' get loaded or just 'X' and not 'Y'?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what media queries are for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this by setting different background images based on the media query.

Unfortunately you cannot set the source of an image tag (only with javascript).

Example:

```
.container {
  background-image: url(big.jpg);
}

@media all and (max-width: 699px) {
  .container {
    background-image: url(small.jpg); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the CSS Media Type and screen size to display different backgrounds.
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Answer (score 1):

Yes this what media query do

You can create two css for every screen size for example:

```
@import url("test.css") screen and (min-width: 960px);
@import url("testmobile.css") screen and (max-width:  959px);
```

or you can add the media query on each css rule.

```
@media all and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px) {
}
```

Please check this [link](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/), it helps you